# Haskell: recursively process lists nested arbitrarily deep

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, types

I'm learning Haskell and would like to write functions to recursively process lists nested arbitrarily deep.

For example I'd like to write `recurReverse`, which in the basis case, acts just like the built in `reverse`, but when passed a nested list, would `reverse` all the elements of the sublists recursively as well:

```
recurReverse [1,2]
>> [2,1]
recurReverse [[1],[2],[3,4]]
>> [[4,3],[2],[1]]
recurReverse [[[1,2]]]
>> [[[2,1]]]
```

Currently I have the basic `reverse` down:

```
rev [] = []
rev (h:t) = rev t ++ [h]
```

But I need more than this -- in the case when the head `h` is also a list (as opposed to an atom in the LISP sense), I'd like to be able to `reverse` `h` as well and return something like `rev t ++ [rev h]`. When I try that, I get a compiler error saying something like I can't `rev h` because `rev` is of type `[t] -> [t]` but I'm trying to call it on type `t`, which makes sense. How can I get around this?

Comment: What it comes down to is you will need to write a type for the list which encodes the depth of nesting at the type level, so that you can write a function recursive not on the *list* but on the *nesting depth*. Probably the simplest way to do this is with type families.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> as opposed to an atom in the LISP sense

Well, there is no such thing in Haskell. Any type which you don't know a priori (which you can't, if you're doing recursion over types) could possibly be a list itself. There's no notion of atomicity, of “not-list-being” which you could use as a base case for this recursion.

That is, unless you make the distinction explicit. This can be done quite nicely in Haskell, with GADTs:

```
data Nest t where
   Egg :: t -> Nest t
   Nest :: [Nest t] -> Nest [t]

nestReverse :: Nest t -> Nest t
nestReverse (Egg x) = Egg x
nestReverse (Nest xs) = Nest . reverse $ map nestReverse xs
```

If you don't like this... well, there is another way, but it's considered ugly / un–Haskell‑ish.

```
class Atomeous l where
  recurReverse :: l -> l

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Atomeous l where
  recurReverse = id
instance Atomeous l => Atomeous [l] where
  recurReverse = reverse . map recurReverse
```

Now, `recurReverse` has your intended behaviour. The first instance is for “atomic” types; because it is marked [`OVERLAPPABLE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap) the compiler will only use this instance if it can't find “a better one” – which it does precisely for lists; these get the recursive call over all elements.

Comment: thanks! so is it safe to say that polymorphism is almost always needed if I want to be able to get around Haskell's type system and work with  "dynamic " recursive data structures (e.g. trees)?

Comment: Not at all! Polymorphism is super userful for writing generic code, but you can perfectly well write recursive data structures as monomorphic ADTs alone. Note that a tree in Haskell is something completely different from a nested list. Lists specifically have a _flat / homogeneous_ structure, very much unlike they do in Lisp.